# Some menu screens have sides "cut off" on 4:3 screen resolutions in Mass Effect 1 (unreal engine 3)

Tags: pc, mass-effect

Playing Mass Effect 1 on PC (v1.02 on steam).

At 4:3 resolutions like 1200x1600 (useful for non-widescreen monitors and projectors), some menu screens display incorrectly: the left and right hand sides of the screen are clipped (as if "zoomed in" too far), so important information cannot be seen (like journal details and the map legend).

Screens affected include:

- Map,
- Party Selection
- Planet details
- Journal

It works fine when using 16:9 screen resolution when playing, like 1920x1080.

**Anyone know how to fix this?**

It's an Unreal Engine 3 game, so hacking the ini files might work if there is an applicable option somewhere, but I haven't found one yet. Similar fixes for other unreal engine 3 games might work, too.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't help the issue, but PC Gaming Wiki is usually pretty good about this and says [the only known fix is to switch to 16:9](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Mass_Effect#Issues_unresolved).

Comment: I actually wrote that myself while trying to find a fix for this issue.